# Error: Cannot find module 'entities/lib/decode_codepoint.js'

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, express

I am using cheerio module for web scraping . It require htmlparser2 module , after installing htmlparser2. it gives following error-

```
Error: Cannot find module 'entities/lib/decode_codepoint.js'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your terminal:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
```

Seen here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-jshint

Answer (score 0):

Below is applicable to Windows environment only, not Linux.

I received the same error when I tried to build [jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) from source on Windows. It turns out that jsdom and/or grunt-contrib-jshint (both of which depend on htmlparser2) require [gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) and for gyp to work you need a c++ compiler and python. I thought that I had them but turned out, that python need to be version 2.x not version 3.x. If it is 3.x it gives you a proper error on the first run (that I missed) and on subsequent runs you are getting the error in the question above which makes you wonder what's going on.

So I uninstalled python 3.x, installed python 2.x (don't forget make sure that python.exe is in your path), then deleted the node_modules folder in the project root and ran the build again.

This time around it worked. I'm not sure if this solves the OP question, but I hope it helps *someone*.